# Looking for simple, working Ws2812 led lib

Tags: python, lib, thonny

In my project I want to include 5 ws2812 leds and color them indivudual (no further effects). I tried a lot of libs but none worked. One asked for supervisor privileges, other failed in executing the library.
Does anybody know of a simple way to make these leds work on GPIO-pin 18, which seems to be the best pin for that?

Tried adafruit and all the found 2812 libs in the package manager from thonny.